# What is the variance of a constant raised to a random variable?

Tags: variance

What is the variance of a constant $k$ raised to a random exponent $x$?

$$Var(k^x)=?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k >0$ this quantity is related to the [moment-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of $X$.  Letting $t \equiv \ln k$ you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{V}(k^X) = \mathbb{V}( \exp (t X)) 
&= \mathbb{E}( \exp (2t X)) - \mathbb{E}( \exp (t X))^2 \\[6pt]
&= m_X(2t) - m_X(t)^2. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The specific functional form varies according to the distribution of $X$, and can easily be obtained by substitution of the form of the moment-generating function.  In the case where $k <0$ then $\ln k$ is complex, and the quantity is related to the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)), but it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks! So if $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $V(k^X) = e^{\mu \ln(k) + 2 \sigma^2 \ln(k)^2} - e^{2 \mu \ln(k) + \sigma^2 \ln(k)^2}$?

Comment: In first exponential, variance term should be divided by two, not multiplied by two.  Other than that, assuming $k>0$, that looks fine.